# Does Brick Heck from The Middle have Asperger syndrome?

Tags: the-middle

It was not directly mentioned in the series, but Brick often behaves as Aspies do:

- He loves reading everything
- Has weird hobbies such as fonts
- If he likes something, he has huge knowledge about the topic
- Has problems with socialization, or he does not have any interest in making friends
- He is very clever and due to that is considered a 'nerd'

Does Brick have Asperger syndrome? Also, he has a tendency to repeat words by whispering them, could this mean Tourette's syndrome?

Comment: Whispering words that you've already said isn't a symptom of Tourette's. It certainly isn't the one that a TV sitcom would choose to depict. I believe it may actually be yet another symptom of ASD/Asperger's.

Comment: while that's a good question, does it matter if he has any syndrome? he's considered special, and his family accept him